# How to test for a potential linear and/or categorical or binary relationships between two variables in the same column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use Scipy and Pandas to find if there is a correlation between pageviews and clicks of the event column. As far as I know, I can find the linear or binary relationship between two different columns using Pandas and Scipy and test for the significance of the relationship. However, I do not know how to test for the relationship between two variables that belong to the same column.

In summary here is what I am trying to do:
***Is there any correlation between clicks and previews on a link? Is it significant? How large is the effect? And I want to test for potential linear as well as categorical (think binary) relationships between both variables***

Below is a sample from my data frame:
[image]

And this is what I tried to do:
I got all the value counts of the different variables in the event columns

```
    df.event.value_counts()
```

I then filtered out the click and pageview events as follows

```
    pageviews = df.loc[df.event == 'pageview']
    clicks = df.loc[df.event == 'click']
```

And tried to run the corr() function on the two variables like this

```
    df.pageviews.corr(clicks)
```

But the corr() method did not work.

But this solution certainly does not work. How could I use Scipy and Pandas to test for the relationship between the pageview and click in the event column?

Comment: What does it mean to have a "linear relationship" if you're referring to two different values that can be taken by the same variable? You might have to do some feature engineering.

Comment: Can you please include your code here?

Comment: @dsillman2000 this is what I am asked to do: Is there any correlation between clicks and previews on a link? Is it significant? How large is the effect? Make sure to at least test for potential linear as well as categorical (think binary) relationships between both variables.

Comment: @erip I have included the code I came up with. i used pandas corr() method as seen above but that does not work

Comment: I mean please include the code as not an image. :-) I want to be able to copy and paste the smallest example that you'd tried.

Comment: @erip I have edited the post with my code included.